# Aligning items on Ant design tables using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox, frontend, antd

I'm working with Ant design tables and using flex for the CSS. Here's what the table looks like (`files-list-table`):

[image: files-list-table]

My expected behavior for this table is for the action items (download+delete/open+delete) to be vertically aligned with the `Action` header on top. Ant design's documentation shows they'll be aligned by default but for me it isnt'. Here's a screenshot of one of the action cells:

[image: table-action]

Here's the CSS I'm using for this table:

```
     /* this container is for the entire page */
     .files-page-container{
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
       flex-direction: column;
       flex: 1 1 auto;
       align-items:center;
     }

     .files-list-table{
        width: 80%;
      }

     .table-cell{
        display: flex; 
        margin-left: auto; 
      }

      .table-action{
         padding-left: 30%;
      }
```

The problem I'm having is in order to make the action items align with the Action header on top, I need to add `padding-left` to it, which is not ideal in this case because the moment I change the screen size, the alignment breaks. I've tried doing `display:flex` on `table-cell` and `table-action` but that makes it worse. That causes the file/folder name to be positioned around the center of the table. Is there any way that I can align the action items without hard-coding them and ensure that they're responsive?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken in thinking, this could be what you're looking for when working with flexboxes: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#article-header-id-6

Comment: This is what I've used to come up with the CSS I've written above.

Comment: Give a fiddle link